# Как избавиться от фокуса при старте Xamarin Forms?

Tags: android, xamarin, клавиатура, фокус

В приложение на XamarinForms 5.0(используется пока только Андроид) при старте у меня открывается диалоговое окно для ввода логина и пароля. Автоматически фокус устанавливается на поле логина и открывается виртуальная клавиатура для ввода, что мягко говоря раздражает, поскольку она закрывает половину формы и пользователь попросту не видит половины интерфейса. Просмотрел кучу советов в сети так и не смог найти решение для того чтобы клавиатура при старте не показывалась:

- использовал unfocus;
- пытался делать поле ввода не активным через enabled;
- делал сервис для скрытия виртуальной клавиатуры;
- для андроида задавал свойство
  android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" (может где-то не там, не силен)
- на Focused() пытался скрыть клавиатуру асинхронно со стартом через
  заданное время;
- на OnAppearing() пытался скрыть клавиатуру асинхронно со стартом через заданное время;

но после появления формы фокус выставляется, и только в последнем случае скрывается если форма до конца загрузилась и успела установить фокус. В таком случае моргает клавиатура, что терпимо, но тоже выглядит как-то не солидно.

Сам момент установки фокуса при первом старте как отловить не знаю? У кого есть опыт поделитесь знанием как сделать это правильно.